# How to add data to spinner dynamically? Keep the spinner data when every time the activity creates. Android

Tags: java, android, android-activity, dynamic, android-spinner

*[update]*  I fix the mistake I made. now the spinner can update dynamically. But every time I launch this new activity, the spinner will be empty, how can I keep the old data when the activity be created again?

I have an EditView, a Button, and a spinner. When the user types in an item in EditView that is not in the spinner, they can click the button to add to the spinner for the next time to save time.
I search for some solutions in StackOverflow and google, but after I click the button, it still not work, the data still not add to the spinner. Here is the part of the code:

```
    purchasedProduct=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.purchasedP);
    spinner=(Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner);
    spinnerBtn=(Button)findViewById(R.id.purchasedDBtn);
    items =new ArrayList<String>();
    items.add("");

    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,items);
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

    spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
    spinnerBtn.setOnClickListener(spinnerBtnListener);
    spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new Spinner.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
            purchasedProduct.setText(adapterView.getSelectedItem().toString());
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {

        }
    });
}

private Button.OnClickListener spinnerBtnListener = new Button.OnClickListener(){

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        String listItem = purchasedProduct.getText().toString();

        //check if already there
        for(int i = 0;i < adapter.getCount();i++)
        {
            if(listItem.equals(adapter.getItem(i)))
                return;
        }
        //check if type in is empty
        if(!listItem.equals(""))
        {
            adapter.clear();
            items.add(listItem);
            adapter.addAll(items);
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();


        }
    }
};
```

Can anyone tell me how to fix it? thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You need to store new data in SQLite database. On start activity you just get data from database. All data in database save on device. See how to use SQLite in Android Studio.

Also you can try store data in XML JSON or text file, but this is bad idea.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Room Persistence Library`, [Look Here for details](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/room).

This library helps you create a cache of your app's data on a device that's running your app. This cache, which serves as your app's single source of truth, allows users to view a consistent copy of key information within your app, regardless of whether users have an internet connection.